# Assembly-reference tag synonym

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

[assembly-reference](/questions/tagged/assembly-reference) and [assembly-references](/questions/tagged/assembly-references) are synonyms.

There can be only one! I suppose it's the singular variant, since [array](/questions/tagged/array) contains [arrays](/questions/tagged/arrays).

Comment: But yes, should probably be a synonym.